# Pull changes from Github from a ruby app running on Heroku

Tags: heroku

If a ruby app is running on Heroku, is it possible to pull changes from Github and run a rake task? I've added some code to call `exec git pull` when an endpoint is requested, however the Heroku logs just tell me that the "App has crashed". Perhaps Heroku doesn't allow apps to do this?

Here is my setup:

- An [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) blog running on Heroku
- A Heroku cedar stack with a [heroku-buildpack-ruby-octopress](https://github.com/jgarber/heroku-buildpack-ruby-octopress)

What I'm attempting to do is expose an endpoint via Sinatra to run the following process:

- Github receives blog post changes
- Github executes the post-receive hook to hit an URL
- App on Heroku receives URL request and does a `git pull` and `rake generate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this because the application you have running on a dyno and the Git repo are two different things.

When you push to Heroku, you're pushing into Git.  This repo is then used to generate a 'slug' which is then deployed to dynos.  This slug contains your application and all it's dependencies, ***not*** the entire git repo.

Therefore, running any Git commands from your application code will not work.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some other reasons too but you can't do a pull because the filesystem of your app is read-only so you can't add any new files to it.

Comment: Can you set Heroku apps to have write access?

Comment: If you use the Cedar stack then you actually can write to the filesystem (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-isolation#ephemeral_filesystem) but the repository metadata is probably not deployed to the dyno with all the other files...

Comment: Hrm this makes me think that it's easier to use a VPS whose file system I can control